# Endpoint of Web App deployed on local service fabric cluster

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Novice here. This might be a very simple queston.
I've a ASP.NET Core web application that exposes following API
http://localhost:1500/api/product

This is how my ServiceManifest.xml looks like

```
 <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="ProductService" UseImplicitHost="true" />
</ServiceTypes>

<EntryPoint>
    <ExeHost>
        <Program>Product.Api.exe</Program>
        <Arguments></Arguments>
        <WorkingFolder>PackageFolder</WorkingFolder>
    </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>

<Resources>
    <Endpoints>
        <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ProductEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="1500" />
    </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

I can get the response while deploying locally through kestrel server but I don't get any response when it's deployed to local cluster on the service fabric.
What can be possible endpoints and which all files can I search to look for possible endpoints? I'm using postman to get response.